# Is it true that Netty provides non-blocking IO only for network?

Tags: java, io, netty, nio

Is my understanding correct that Netty provides non-blocking io (NIO) only for network? And if you want to make a blocking io (i.e. database query), you have to use executer from ChannelHandlerContext in order to not to block EventLoop?

Comment: The problem doesn't have to do with the network; it's the blocking nature of JDBC drivers.  There is an effort to write a non-blocking JDBC driver for JDK 9, but it's not there yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct that Netty provides non-blocking io (NIO) only for network?

It would be more accurate to say that *Java* only provides non-blocking I/O for network channels. See the list of classes which extend [`SelectableChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html).

> And if you want to make a blocking io (i.e. database query), you have to use executer from `ChannelHandlerContext` in order to not to block EventLoop?

Yes.